# Unable to schedule a task from within a UNNotificationServiceExtension - Error: BGTaskSchedulerErrorDomain error 1

Tags: ios, swift, background-process, unnotificationserviceextension

As the title states, i am currently unable to schedule a task from within a UNNotificationServiceExtension. I would like to schedule the task when the following function is called and thus a push is received:

`func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)`

Currently as soon as i call:

`try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)`

The catch clause is entered and the following error is returned: 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (BGTaskSchedulerErrorDomain error 1.)'

The push messages are send with Firebase cloud messaging via the following url and are received perfectly in my app: https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/{path to project}. I call this url from within POSTMAN. I also specify the access token and the json body.

The apns header in the push message is set to "apns-push-type": "background". And the payload.aps has the following values: "apns-priority": "5","content-available": 1, "mutable-content": 1. I think this all works correctly, as i verified this.

The strange thing is that i did get the background task to work from just within the actual app, so without firing it from within the UNNotificationServiceExtension. I tried this to check if the code actually works at all.

**I have done my research and so far i have tried the following already:**
**1.** I made sure 'Permitted background task scheduler identifiers' in the info.plist is filled with the correct task identifier. I have triple checked that this string gets used correctly in the code as well.

**2.** Enabled the following capabilities in the app: 'Background fetch', 'Remote notifications', 'Background processing'.

**3.** In the info.plist the following UIBackgroundModes are supported: 'audio', 'fetch', 'processing', 'remote-notification' and 'voip'. These same UIBackgroundModes are entered in the UNNotificationServiceExtension info.plist as well (i did that just to be sure).

**4.** I made sure the task gets registered in the AppDelegate in 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions'

**5.** I call the 'expirationHandler' and the 'setTaskCompleted' every time the task is actually fired

Any help or guidance is deeply appreciated!
Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the problem is? I have essentially the same setup minus the extension.

Comment: @AndyIbanez Nop, i didn't figure it out yet. We took another approach to the problem.

Answer (score 9):

It seems that background tasks can not be scheduled on a simulator, I got the same error as you when using the simulator. When running on a real device everything is fine. 
Hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I will try this the next time i'm on this project again :-) No idea who downvoted you though.

Comment: No worries, I'm just describing how I solved the problem. And today I just found that my Xcode is outdated for long time so maybe update Xcode to the latest version would help as well. Good luck with you project.